# How do I integrate a Go binding with MetaMask?

Tags: go, solidity, web3js, metamask

I am still learning. I have built a web3/js based front end that deploys and interacts with a contract where others can contribute ETH (a kickstarter-type contract). Everything works fine, with MetaMask kicking in for any payable transaction. I then built a front/back end app using Go. I deployed the same Solidity contract and ran it through abigen to produce a Golang bindings file. I can interact with the contract bind file only by hard-coding my private key, or passing it through the front end.

What I can't find info on is how to integrate MetaMask with the bindings, so other folks can contribute to the contract. I'd very much appreciate knowing if this is even possible, and if so, could you point me in the right direction? I've got this far but I'm stumped!

Thanks very much.

Comment: you should never sign users transactions on the backend by sending private keys over the network, it would defeat the purpose of non-custodial wallets. I would suggest you use the abigen generated file to only query the contract; maybe do authenticated interactions (such as deploys) only if you can ensure your private key remains off-line.

Comment: Oh for sure. The pk was a test for explaining what I can and cannot do with the abigen file. There must be a way to cause Metamask to sign the tx though. I'll keep looking.  Thanks.

Comment: You can run Go in the browser via wasm. But if you think to hide your private key that way, it's futile. The *only* way to have a secure dapp is to use the user's own key and for the rest rely on the security of the smart contract.

Comment: Thanks but what I thought should be possible is to replicate the functionality of a web app based on web3 and javascript and engaging MetaMask with a web app based on golang and the abigen bindings. If it can't be done, what's the point if all you can do is call non-payable go functions?

Comment: Wasm looks interesting though. Thanks for tHE tip!